# Codeigniter dynamic form dropdown, not returning value but the ID

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have this code for my drop down form that worked fine

```
<?php echo form_label('Model: ', 'model'); ?>
<?php echo form_dropdown('model', $model_dropdown, '', set_value('model', '', 'id="model"')); ?>

<?php echo form_label('Make: ', 'make'); ?>
<?php echo form_dropdown('make', $make_dropdown, '', set_value('make', '', 'id="make"')); ?>
```

but then I wanted to enhance it with some jquery for a dynamic drop down so I changed it to this

```
<label for="make">Make: </label>
<?php echo form_dropdown('id', $make_dropdown, '', 'id="make"'); ?><br /></td>

<?php $models['#'] = 'Please Select'; ?>
<label for="model">Model: </label>
<?php echo form_dropdown('model_id', $models, '', 'id="models"'); ?><br /></td>
```

with this for js

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#make').change(function(){
        $("#models > option").remove();
        var id = $('#make').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "site/get_models/"+id,
            datatype : "json",

            success: function(models)            {
                $.each(models,function(id,model)
                {
                    var opt = $('<option />');
                    opt.val(id);
                    opt.text(model);
                    $('#models').append(opt);
                });
            }

        });

    });
});
```

but now the value is not being submitted but the ID, which makes sense when looking at the code. What needs to be updated to fix this?

Thanks

Edit: The ID of the Make and Model drop down is what is being inserted, I want the value instead, like how it use to work before I added the jquery.

For instance, the make drop down would have HP or Dell and the model would have models, when submitted, those values would be inserted but instead I'm just getting the IDs...

Comment: need to explain issue in better detail

Comment: added an edit to the question

Comment: url: "site/get_models/"+id  <-- does this line actually work?  i find using base_url() in the ajax call works.  is your server getting data from the ajax request?

Comment: what is being returned in the ajax response...json? If it is html get rid of the "each" in success

Comment: @chrisvillanueva it does work, I removed part of the url for this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing:

```
opt.val(id);
```

to

```
opt.val(model);
```

update:
ok, so this works for one data structure type. i would suggest defining the return value type where you could do something like this:

-->"successData" from the ajax request = {"type":"model","id":"12345","model":"a cool model"}

and your success handle could do something like:

```
    success: function(successData){

        if(successData.type === "model"){
          //do your loop to create the models markup
        else{
           //we have "make" data, handle that here..
        }
    }
```

Comment: This fixed the model, thank you. What can I do for the make? For the JS code I need the ID for the first value in the form_dropdown but I need the value for the db submit. Ideas?

Comment: what data is return to the success method?  does the return value have a way to signify whether it's for "make" or "model"? if you can distinguish between the two, then you can make an "if" statement in the success handler to define the inputs as needed.

Comment: what data is return to the success method? does the return value have a way to signify whether it's for "make" or "model"? 

I'm not sure... I'm still learning and I pieced this together with the Googles...

Comment: i would think it helps.  if you expect two return value types, then you should have a hash or property to identify the type.  you are expecting a json response, right?  you could have a return value like {"type":"make", "id":"1234", "make":"fancy car"}.  do the something similar for "model".  then in your success handler, test for the return type using an "if" statement.  then handle each case accordingly.

Comment: you are still blowing my mind but I'll do more reading based on what you are suggesting.

Comment: look at my updated answer.  it will show you how easy this is to do.